# Is it possible to use the premium "HTTP" action i nPower automate for SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

I know there is the "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action, but it doesn't have pagination out-of-the-box.

Obviously I can build a Do-Until sequence, but just wondering if it's possible to just use the HTTP request. It's not working for me (error message: enter a valid uri) and I am wondering if this is because of authentication or something. Is it even possible to use this connector within Power Automate for a sharepoint site in the tenant?

Thanks!